# Broadcasting Server to Client C

Tags: c, broadcastreceiver, client-server, communication

I am trying to broadcast a UDP message from the server to client. I would like for the server to send the broadcast to the client and then for the client to acknowledge the broadcast. They both compile with no errors but the server will not send the broadcast. The server says it successfully binds. Any tips would be helpful please.

Client.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 8081

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

int clientsocket;
int reuse = 1;
int reuseaddr;
int bind_sock;
int rec_broad;
int send_ack;
char dgram[512];
char client_message[2000];
struct sockaddr_in serv_address;
struct sockaddr_in group;


if (argc != 3) {
   printf("Command line args should be multicast group and port\n");
   printf("(e.g. for SSDP, `listener 239.255.255.250 1900`)\n");
   return 1;
}

clientsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(clientsocket < 0){
    printf("\n\tSocket not created.\n");
    exit(1);
}
else printf("\n\tSocket created successfully.\n");

reuseaddr = setsockopt(clientsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse));
if(reuseaddr < 0){
    printf("\n\tSetting REUSEADDR error.\n");
    exit(1);
}
else printf("\n\tREUSEADDR Successful.\n");

serv_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
serv_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

/*bind_sock = bind(clientsocket, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_address, sizeof(serv_address));
if(bind_sock < 0){
    printf("\n\tBind unsuccessful.\n");
    exit(1);
}
else printf("\n\tBind Successful.\n");*/

strcpy(client_message, "Acknowledged.\n");

for(;;){

    printf("\nListening........\n");

    rec_broad = recvfrom(clientsocket, dgram, sizeof(dgram), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_address, sizeof(serv_address));
    if(rec_broad < 0){
        printf("\n\tBroadcast not received.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else printf("\n\tBroadcast received successfully.\n");

    send_ack = sendto(clientsocket, client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_address, sizeof(serv_address));
    if (send_ack < 0){
        printf("\n\tAck not sent.\n");
    }
    else printf("\n\tAcknowledge sent successfully.\n");

}

return 0;
}
```

Server.c

```
      #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 8081
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#endif

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int serv_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in broadcast_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int b_addr_len;
    int ret;
    int bind_sock;
    int yes = 1;
    char buffer[2000];
    int send_broad;
    int z;


//Create socket
serv_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(serv_socket < 0){
    printf("\n\tProblem1.\n");
    exit(1);
}
else printf("\n\tSocket made successful.\n");

//Setsockopt
ret = setsockopt(serv_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&yes, sizeof(yes));
if(ret < 0){
    printf("\n\tSetsockopt error.\n");
    return -1;
}
else printf("\n\tSetsockopt successful.\n");

b_addr_len = sizeof(broadcast_addr);

//Broadcast Address
memset((void*)&broadcast_addr, 0, b_addr_len);
broadcast_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
broadcast_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
broadcast_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

//Bind socket with client
bind_sock = bind(serv_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, b_addr_len);
if (ret < 0){
    printf("\n\tBind unsuccessful.\n");
    exit(1);
}
else printf("\n\tBind successful.\n");

memset(buffer, '\0', 2000);
strcpy(buffer, "This is the broadcast!\n");

//Send broadcast
send_broad = sendto(serv_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&broadcast_addr, b_addr_len);
if(send_broad < 0){
    printf("\n\tBroadcast not sent.\n");
    exit(1);
}
else printf("\n\tBroadcast sent OK.\n");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. How do you know it's not sending the broadcast?

Comment: You're using `239.x.x.x` which is a _multicast_ address (i.e. using the term _broadcast_ is a bit of a misnomer). You need a `setsockopt` with `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` [on the client]. Search on: `multicast add membership`. One result: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~jeffay/dirt/FAQ/comp249-001-F99/mcast-socket.html